# How do I show that this function is monotonically decreasing?

Tags: hypergeometric-function, monotone-functions

I'd like to show that the following function is monotonically decreasing (from plotting it is obvious that it is):

$$f(n)=\frac{c\,(n^2-n)\, {}_2F_1(1,\, 2-n;\, n^2-2n+3;\, c)}{n^2-2n+2}$$

with domain the integers greater than 3 and with $0<c<1$. *Mathematica* gives me the derivative, but the expression looks rather complicated (again involving the hypergeometric function), and I can't tell what its sign is.

Can someone tell me how to proceed in this case?

Comment: have you tried to reduce it any ?

Comment: I haven't, but that's just because I don't know how to do that. If you think that's the best way to proceed, could you provide a bit more detail?

Comment: you can change the denominator and some of the arguments to a form using n-1 I was mostly just hoping there might then be a common factor realized to reduce the rational expression. denominator is (n-1)^2+1 for example.

Comment: I see. No, I didn't find any useful simplifications.